# How to prevent resetting font size by the aligned environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, fontsize, math-fonts

I want the lines under the second quantifier to be aligned at `∈`, so I'm using `aligned`. (Maybe I should switch to `split`?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\operatornamewithlimits
\forall_{a, b \in \mathbb Z}
\mathop
{\exists!}
_{\begin{aligned}
q &\in \mathbb Z \\
r &\in \mathbb Z _b
\end{aligned}}
a=qb+r
\]
\end{document}
```

But the lines get rendered apparently in normal font, not smaller like it should be for subscripts and can be observed under the first quantifier. How can it be fixed?

Other answers at the site for the problem of custom aligning multiline subscripts offer low level solutions, less elegant IMO, involving modifying the `subarray` environment. I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the `amsmath` package, you could use its `\substack` macro to render the material below `\exists!` in scriptstyle math mode. (`align` and `split` use displaystyle math mode, which is simply much too large for the task at hand.) Alignment within the `\substack` material may be achieved with the help of a suitably placed `\hfill` ("horizontal fill") directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \operatornamewithlimits and \substack macros
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb macro

\begin{document}
\[
\operatornamewithlimits\forall_{a, b \in \mathbb{Z}}  \,
\operatornamewithlimits{\exists!}%
  _{\substack{q\in \mathbb{Z} \hfill \\ 
              r\in \mathbb{Z}_b}}       \!
a=qb+r
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But wouldn't that cause alignment to the left instead of at ∈?

Comment: @ByteEater -- it so happens that the letters `q` and `r` have almost exactly the same width -- 3.91634pt and 3.92825pt in Computer Modern math-mode, with `\scriptstyle` in effect. (`r` is only 0.3% wider than `q`.) Should you be a stickler for extreme-precision typesetting, though, do replace `q\in\mathbb{Z}\hfill` with `\hfill q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\hphantom{b}}`.

Comment: I've upvoted the answer, once supplemented with your comment. But can this approach be made more robust? If there were an arbitrary number of lines with arbitrary lengths of contents before and after the desired alignment points, possibly unknown, or likely to change, I'd have to make nonlocal changes and the code size would grow quadratically. And even that only assuming there exists (I suppose so) a function in LaTeX giving the maximum of two widths (for use inside the numerous `\phantom`s).

Comment: @ByteEater - The job TeX and LaTeX are designed to perform is *typesetting*. Nothing more, nothing less. To me, your positing of "an arbitrary number of lines with arbitrary lengths of contents before and after the desired alignment points, possibly unknown, or likely to change" doesn't sound like it might have any recognizable relationship to typesetting. I thus strongly suspect that TeX are LaTeX are inadequate, or worse, for the problem you say you are looking to solve. For all I know, their code size might grow not quadratically, but exponentially, in the realm of problems you wish to fix.

Comment: Fair enough. So, e.g. code generation is an explicit non-goal. And I'm supposed to measure which letters or whole expressions are longer. Moreover, if something changes (not necessarily the contents) that affects which one is the longest, refactoring is necessary (even with only two lines). (Not that I need any of that for the problem at hand. Just perusing the opportunity to learn about LaTeX in general. Especially the ways in which it's so different from what I've become used to taking for granted in other computer languages.)

Answer (score 2):

One alternative, in this case, might be to use an `\alignLongstack` for the subscript, since `\scriptstyle` can be set as the `\TABstackMathstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
\setstackgap{L}{.7\normalbaselineskip}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\operatornamewithlimits
\forall_{a, b \in \mathbb Z}
\mathop
{\exists!}_{\alignLongstack{q \in& \mathbb Z \\ r \in& \mathbb Z _b}}
a=qb+r
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I'd be tempted to insert `\,` (thinspace) between the two operator expressions.

Comment: By "the two operator expressions" you mean the quantifiers?

Comment: @ByteEater - Look for the instance of `\,` in my answer.

Comment: Is the `.7` arbitrarily chosen to make the result look nice?

Comment: I've probably never come across the `tabstackengine` package before, it seems rarely used. Can a similar effect be obtained with just `amsmath`? Is there an environment that allows custom alignment but respects the inherited font style (smaller for subscripts)? Or maybe an environment (somewhat like `minipage`) that can have `aligned` inside but sets the defaults according to the context, so that they're used by the `aligned` environment?

Comment: @ByteEater In one sense, .7 is arbitrary, to make the result look nice.  But it has physical significance, which is the (approx) height ratio of an `x` between script-size and normal-size.

Comment: `tabstackengine` is certainly no replacement for `amsmath` and does not masquerade as such.  However, there are times when it may, in a limited way, prove more convenient at achieving a unique typesetting requirement.